# What could be it?

Tags: knowledge, cipher, history

It was too 6-6-500, then I've decided to 1009 it with more color, but it became too 54-1-500.

What could be it?

Comment: I think 'too' might become '2'

Comment: @Daedric it looks okay to me, but if you think it needs a fix, be my guest.

Comment: Sorry no offense, i'd really need to know the answer / what you're saying; to edit it properly.

Comment: @Oray: My edit is actually empty. I tried to change the [history] tag to [historical], but they are handled as synonymes.

Answer (score 11):

Partial answer:

> If we convert the numbers to Roman numerals, we get that 6-6-500 is "VIVID", 1009 is "MIX" and 54-1-500 is "LIVID". So the first sentence becomes 
>  
>
>  "It was too vivid, then I've decided to mix it with more color, but it became too livid."

Comment: So one guess could be that **it** is **paint**!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> red

based on the partial answer

> red is a color which is vivid, then I mix it with blue to get a livid color, which is purple